# Create 2d array in Tkinter

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, 2d

I'm just working on a new project in Python with Tkinter. I'm a newbie in Python, so I need some help. I want to create 2D array and show it in a window.

Here is my code:

```
maze =[[player(), invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock()],
      [invisblock(),invisblock(),invisblock(), invisblock()],
      [invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock()],
      [invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock(), invisblock()],  ]
```

Player looks like:

```
def player():
    block = tkinter.Label(window)
    block.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="down.png")
    block['image'] = block.image
    block.config(text='karel_down')
    return block
```

And printing like:

```
def printt():
    for i, block_row in enumerate(map):
        for j, block in enumerate(block_row):
            block.grid(row=i, column=j)
    window.update()
    window.after(250)
```

Everything works fine, but I have a small problem.
I want to make another function like this (this is not functional right now):

```
def create_world(row,col):
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
             maze[i][j] = invisblock()
```

So I want to fill all my maze with row and col from create_world with invisblock(). Example: create_world(10,10) and will create maze 10x10 invisblock(). I don't want to fill manually like in my first code sample (maze =[[player()...) but with a function. In short, I want to create the initial array of objects "smarter". Thanks!!

Comment: Want you need is the `grid()` method

Comment: @HugoDelahaye: I don't think that is what is being asked. The problem isn't in laying out the widgets, the problem is in creating the initial array of objects.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, that's true! I want to create the initial array of objects "smarter"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
def create_world(row,col):
    return [[invisiblock() for i in range(col)] for j in range(row)] 

maze = create_world(10, 10)
```